# How to stop my service running from VS Code extension while upgrading the VS Code to new version?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-debugger, vscode-tasks

I have a VS Code extension installed which runs a java service from extension location.

But I am getting below error while updating the VS Code to a new version because of the running jar.

"**Failed to create file handle: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.**"

I need to stop my service whenever the VS Code update happens ( Both automatic and manual updates ).

Is there any way to get control over VS Code update in my extension code?

Any help is much appreciated!

[image: VS Code Update Error]

Answer (score -1):

just run vscode as administrator and update